# d3-celestial library export to SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas, svg

I am using the D3-Celestial Library (https://github.com/ofrohn/d3-celestial) and trying to convert the canvas image, to an SVG (I need to use this as a Vector image so it can be converted to GCode for a laser cutter).
I have tried using the Fabric JS library and Canvas-GetSVG with no success.
Does anyone have a good place to start or easy way to do this?

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;"><div id="celestial-map"></div></div>
<div id="celestial-form"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas;
Celestial.display({
  form: true,
  location: true,
  datapath: "../data/",
  stars: {proper: true}
});
document.getElementById("celestial-map").firstChild.setAttribute("id", "findthisstring");

function myFunction(){
   var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('findthisstring', { isDrawingMode: true });
   canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
   canvas.toSVG();
 }
 function do_save() {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('findthisstring', { isDrawingMode: true });
    canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
    var filedata=canvas.toSVG(); // the SVG file is now in filedata

    var locfile = new Blob([filedata], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
    var locfilesrc = URL.createObjectURL(locfile);//mylocfile);

    var dwn = document.getElementById('dwn');
    dwn.innerHTML = "<a href=" + locfilesrc + " 
    download='mysvg.svg'>Download</a>";
  }
  </script>

 <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
 <input type="button" id="saveBtn" value="save" onclick="do_save()"></input>
 <div id='dwn'></div>
 <div id="imgOut"></div>
```

I tried to use a few different libraries to export the data from the Canvas object to a SVG, but only was able to get Empty SVGs.

Comment: In order to help you, we need to see your code. Please edit your question to include the relevant snippets of code, along with an explanation of what you have tried, and your expected output.

Comment: I added the JS and the relevant HTML, does this help explain what I am looking to do?

Answer (score 0):

Fabric.js is no magic bullet to convert pixel-oriented `<canvas>` content to vector format. Only things that were drawn **using`fabric.Canvas` methods** can be exported to a vector format.

How does that work? From a Fabric.js perspective, if you initialize a Canvas object, that canvas is empty. Previously drawn content is simply ignored. If the `fabric.Canvas` object is given a command, two things happen: changes are drawn to the HTML `<canvas>` element, overwriting existing content, and the changes are recorded in a data structure. Only these data can be used by the `.toSVG()` method for exporting to SVG. The canvas element itself is a write-only output device.

To repeat it plainly: `<canvas>` elements contain no vector information. The optimum you could expect to extract, whatever library you use, is something like this:

```
<svg>
  <image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64....." />
</svg>
```

with the data source being a pixel image.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have specifics at hand at the moment, but I was trying to do the same thing (from the frustratingly incomplete Make magazine article) and was able to coerce an SVG by:

Hosting a local instance of d3-celestial

Modifying HTML pages to use the older 0.4 version which actually used SVGs (in dist folder)

Installing "SVG crowbar" bookmarklet to export the output to a file.

Comment: That is perfect.  I was using that article as a basis as well.  That idea worked  a treat.  Got a nice SVG to cut some wood with! THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Bradley, did you figure out how to get the Date/Time or Location to work with v0.4?  Im stuck between the ease of using the older code, and painstakingly converting the PNG output of Canvas in v0.6x to a vector.